# Using a comma with a conjunction to separate long phrases

Tags: commas, adverbials

Every guide I've looked up says you should not use a comma along with a conjunction that joins phrases.  However, this rule often seems to be broken for longer phrases.

For example, every major Bible translation (with the exception of the Good News Translation) includes a comma between the two adverbial prepositional phrases of [Exodus 23:31](https://biblehub.com/exodus/23-31.htm):

> I will set your border from the Red Sea to the Sea of the Philistines, and from the
> wilderness to the Euphrates

Is there a standard rule to follow here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use a comma before "and" or "or"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30516/should-i-use-a-comma-before-and-or-or) Also [Comma or no comma before the word "and"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202945/) [**,**] and more specifically [Usage of a comma before "and" in a fairly complex sentence.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117410/)

Comment: No.  The first two links just lead to statements about the general rule, which I've already stated...I'm asking about published examples which don't follow the rule and whether there are guidelines to making exceptions.  Your last link is about compound sentences, which mine is not.

Comment: That comma is not necessary. Though stylistically, it adds "and-not-only-that" drama.

Comment: A merciful God will give you an opportunity to breathe when reading this aloud. Seriously, it's usually stylistically poor with short coordinated strings, but this is reversed as the strings get longer/more complicated. // Correct punctuation is a separate issue from correct grammar, and often more flexible/disputed.

Comment: OK...I was kind of hoping for guidelines on when a phrase is sufficiently long/complex, but I suppose these explanations will do.